# Laravel Sail, MySQL Database Access Issue with 'sail' User

Tags: mysql, laravel, docker, server, fedora

I am currently working on a Laravel project using Sail. Everything works perfectly locally, including running the artisan migrate command. However, when I try to deploy the project on my Fedora server with a reverse proxy, I encounter a problem when running the migration.

When I run the migration command (./vendor/bin/sail artisan migrate) on the server, I receive the following error:

```
SQLSTATE\[HY000\] \[1045\] Access denied for user 'sail'@'192.168.160.3' (using password: YES) (Connection: mysql, SQL: select \* from information_schema.tables where table_schema = laravel and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')

at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:760
756▕         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
757▕         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
758▕         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
759▕         catch (Exception $e) {
➜ 760▕             throw new QueryException(
761▕                 $this-\>getName(), $query, $this-\>prepareBindings($bindings), $e
762▕             );
763▕         }
764▕     }
```

In order to better understand what might be causing this problem and to get help in solving it, I will detail the complete procedure of tasks I have performed up to the appearance of this issue. I hope that by providing this information, I can get advice and suggestions to finally overcome this obstacle and continue the development of my Laravel project.

- ssh username@server
- nano ../etc/caddy/Caddyfile
- add : " project.domaine { reverse_proxy http://0.0.0.0:80 } "
- systemctl restart caddy
- ssh username@server / mkdir project / cd project
- git clone https://github.com/me/projet.git
- composer install
- ./vendor/bin/sail build --no-cache
- ./vendor/bin/sail up -d
- check url : project.domaine ( error laravel storage..etc... )
- error : file_put_contents(/var/www/html/storage/framework/sessions/kM2GIpbwaSHnIY54hmucO5SdiNXtMD
  Failed to open stream: Permission denied
- Storage error resolution: ./vendor/bin/sail exec laravel.test bash
- chown -R sail:sail storage
- chown -R sail:sail bootstrap/cache
- chmod -R 775 storage
- chmod -R 775 bootstrap/cache
- ./vendor/bin/sail down
- ./vendor/bin/sail up -d
- Storage error resolved (app visible at the address: project.domain)
- ./vendor/bin/sail artisan migrate
- error : Access denied for user 'sail' ...

I'm a bit lost and don't know what to do to resolve this issue. If anyone has any ideas or suggestions, I would be grateful to hear them. I need to resolve this problem so that I can continue working on this project.

Thank you in advance for your help.

my .env

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:ZeM4sQDei27icN6cC1GJMpIAekJAv/yLBp+6c7vjTkc=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost
APP_PORT=80

LOG_CHANNEL=stack
LOG_DEPRECATIONS_CHANNEL=null
LOG_LEVEL=debug

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
#DB_HOST=host.docker.internal.  i try to  
DB_HOST=mysql 
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=laravel
DB_USERNAME=sail
DB_PASSWORD=password
```

my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
    laravel.test:
        build:
            context: ./vendor/laravel/sail/runtimes/8.2
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
            args:
                WWWGROUP: '${WWWGROUP}'
        image: sail-8.2/app
        extra_hosts:
            - 'host.docker.internal:host-gateway'
        ports:
            - '${APP_PORT:-80}:80'
            - '${VITE_PORT:-5173}:${VITE_PORT:-5173}'
        environment:
            WWWUSER: '${WWWUSER}'
            LARAVEL_SAIL: 1
            XDEBUG_MODE: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_MODE:-off}'
            XDEBUG_CONFIG: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_CONFIG:-client_host=host.docker.internal}'
        volumes:
            - '.:/var/www/html'
        networks:
            - sail
        depends_on:
            - mysql
    mysql:
        image: 'mysql/mysql-server:8.0'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_DB_PORT:-3306}:3306'
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: '%'
            MYSQL_DATABASE: '${DB_DATABASE}'
            MYSQL_USER: '${DB_USERNAME}'
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 1
        volumes:
            - 'sail-mysql:/var/lib/mysql'
            - './vendor/laravel/sail/database/mysql/create-testing-database.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/10-create-testing-database.sh'
        networks:
            - sail
        healthcheck:
            test:
                - CMD
                - mysqladmin
                - ping
                - '-p${DB_PASSWORD}'
            retries: 3
            timeout: 5s
networks:
    sail:
        driver: bridge
volumes:
    sail-mysql:
        driver: local
```

Comment: The error message indicates that your mysql user name and/or password is incorrect or does not have access to the database.

Comment: While acknowledging that he is right, I don't understand why this is happening. The password and username are correct, as indicated in the docker-compose.yml and .env files. Perhaps it's an issue with permissions, similar to the storage bug we encountered earlier. To be honest, I'm at a loss as to what's causing the problem.

Comment: You say your user name and password are correct, mysql disagrees with you. I'm sorry, but I side with mysql on this one. You need to double check the users, their passwords and their permissions in mysql.

Comment: The yml only contains the setup of the root user for mysql. You are using a different user to connect.

Comment: Are you sure about that? I thought that MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}' corresponds to the configuration for the root user, while MYSQL_USER: '${DB_USERNAME}' / MYSQL_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}' is for a regular user named 'sail' in this case.

Comment: I tried to connect to the MySQL container manually. Here's the procedure I followed:
"./vendor/bin/sail exec mysql bash"
"mysql -u sail -p my_database_name (laravel)"
"password" 
Unfortunately, I received the following error: "ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'sail'@'localhost' (using password: YES)"
I am indeed encountering the same error as before, but I don't understand why. How am I supposed to link the correct password? If you have any ideas on how to solve this problem, I would be happy to hear them.

Comment: i try with root user, same error ...

Comment: any charitable soul to help me? I would like to understand what I did wrong

Comment: Apparently my problem so stupid seems insoluble

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can FIND out what the MySQL Container is using:

1. List the Docker containers:

   **% sail ps**
2. List the MySQL container ENV settings (replace web3-mysql-1 with your container name):

   **% docker exec web3-mysql-1 env**

[image]

If you are using Docker Desktop, you can simply inspect the container.

[image]